# Reorienting the pandas dataframe with pivot table and groupby function to make multiple row (string) values appear in a single column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

> Any suggestion what is happening here? Here is my dataframe with application number, applicant, gender, title of the application and multiple keywords per application.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Application number': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
        'Applicant': ['John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson','Ryan Rosling','Ryan Rosling','Ryan Rosling','Ryan Rosling','Ryan Rosling','Gee Gettysbeurg','Gee Gettysbeurg','Gee Gettysbeurg'],
        'Gender': ['m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','v','v','v'],
        'Title':['Symplectic symmetry','Symplectic symmetry','Symplectic symmetry','Symplectic symmetry','Symplectic symmetry','Symplectic symmetry', 'Exploring protein synthesis', 'Exploring protein synthesis', 'Exploring protein synthesis', 'Exploring protein synthesis', 'Exploring protein synthesis', 'auxin-response pathway','auxin-response pathway','auxin-response pathway' ],
        'Keyword':['Maths', 'trignometry', 'Analysis', 'Algebra', 'Hypothesis', 'DNA', 'mitochondria', 'RNA', 'Brain', 'Cellstructure', 'Life', 'Blood', 'analysis', 'blood circulation']  })
df.head()
```

> I used to reorient the table to make keywords appear in a single cell per applicant by following code:

```
df_pv2=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Application number', 'Applicant', 'Gender', 'Title'],columns=df.groupby(['Application number', 'Applicant', 'Gender', 'Title']).cumcount().add(1),values=['Keyword'], aggfunc='sum')
df_pv2.columns=df_pv2.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
```

> But now it does not reorient the keyword columns. For the sake of completeness, hereunder the code to clean the table: dropping the not required columns

```
#joining all keywords together, seperated by comma
df_pv2['Keywords'] = df_pv2.loc[:, 'Keyword1':'Keyword6'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1)
df_pv2=df_pv2.drop(df_pv2.loc[:, 'Keyword1':'Keyword6'].columns, axis = 1) 
#resetting index
df_pv2=df_pv2.reset_index()
df_pv2.head()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aggfunc='sum'` will only operate on numeric values, for this reason, this code:

```
df_pv2 = pd.pivot_table(df,
                        index=['Application number', 'Applicant', 'Gender',
                               'Title'],
                        columns=df.groupby(
                            ['Application number', 'Applicant', 'Gender',
                             'Title']
                        ).cumcount().add(1),
                        values=['Keyword'],
                        aggfunc='sum')
```

Produces:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(1, John Johnson, m, Symplectic symmetry), (2, Ryan Rosling, m, Exploring protein synthesis), (3, Gee Gettysbeurg, v, auxin-response pathway)]
```

Which is why the resulting DataFrame has no keywords.

---

One fix would be to use `aggfunc='first'`:

```
df_pv2 = pd.pivot_table(df,
                        index=['Application number', 'Applicant', 'Gender',
                               'Title'],
                        columns=df.groupby(
                            ['Application number', 'Applicant', 'Gender',
                             'Title']
                        ).cumcount().add(1),
                        values=['Keyword'],
                        aggfunc='first')

df_pv2.columns = df_pv2.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)

# joining all keywords together, seperated by comma
df_pv2['Keywords'] = df_pv2.loc[:, 'Keyword1':'Keyword6'].apply(
    lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis=1)
df_pv2 = df_pv2.drop(df_pv2.loc[:, 'Keyword1':'Keyword6'].columns, axis=1)
# resetting index
df_pv2 = df_pv2.reset_index()
```

Which results in:

```
   Application number        Applicant Gender                        Title                                                Keywords
0                   1     John Johnson      m          Symplectic symmetry  Maths, trignometry, Analysis, Algebra, Hypothesis, DNA
1                   2     Ryan Rosling      m  Exploring protein synthesis           mitochondria, RNA, Brain, Cellstructure, Life
2                   3  Gee Gettysbeurg      v       auxin-response pathway                      Blood, analysis, blood circulation
```

---

However, a simple [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) can be used to get directly to this point from `df` without a `pivot_table`:

```
df_pv2 = df.groupby(
    ['Application number', 'Applicant', 'Gender', 'Title'],
)['Keyword'].agg(', '.join).reset_index(name='Keywords')
```

`df_pv2`:

```
   Application number        Applicant Gender                        Title                                                Keywords
0                   1     John Johnson      m          Symplectic symmetry  Maths, trignometry, Analysis, Algebra, Hypothesis, DNA
1                   2     Ryan Rosling      m  Exploring protein synthesis           mitochondria, RNA, Brain, Cellstructure, Life
2                   3  Gee Gettysbeurg      v       auxin-response pathway                      Blood, analysis, blood circulation
```